# Java code logs are returning null instread of a guidPrefix (string value)

Tags: java, string, null, return, prefix

Below, I have written code meant to establish a `guidPrefix` (6 character string) that comes before a 34 character GUID. I have made an input class to initialize strings for guid and guidPrefix, and another class to send GET requests using thge guid. The second class will return a log statement containing the guid and guidPrefix, as shown in the last line of code

When trying to return the guid and guidPrefix in the logs during tests like shown below, the guid is returned by `GuidPrefix` returns as `"GuidPrefix null"`.

What may I change to properly return the guidPrefix in the logs?

```
@JsonIgnore
private String guidPrefix;

public String getGuidPrefix() {
    return guidPrefix;
}

public void setGuidPrefix(String guidPrefix) {
    this.guidPrefix = StringUtils.substring(guidPrefix, 0, guidPrefix.length() - 1);
}


//Log statement that returns guidPrefix as null

@Override
public Input getInput(final UUID uuid, final String prefix) throws InputExceptionn {
    validateGuid(uuid, prefix);

    final SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource(UUID_PARAM, uuid).addvalue(PREFIX_PARAM, prefix);

    try {
        final Input input = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL_FIND, namedParameters, new InputRowMapper());
        LOGGER.info("Retrieved GUID {} GuidPrefix {} ", input.getGUID(),    input.getGuidPrefix());
        return input;
}
```

Comment: I feel like we are missing some code, what is the return at the end of your code?

Comment: Sorry about that, essentially I have two classes. The input class is where the GUID and guidPrefix were initialized, along with their getters and setters. The Logger.info is the end of my second class, where a get request is submitted for a GUID. The return is just a log returning the two strings guid and guidPrefix from the input class.

Comment: Edit: added more code from the implementation class